# how to send our application to other member with security?

Tags: iphone

Iam developed one application.I want to send this application to other member.That person in another state.So how to send my application in secure mode ,how to safe my application from hacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create Ad Hoc distribution of the application and send to other user. Check the apple developer docs for creating Ad Hoc Distribution profile.

Comment: Ok.But that distribute profile is for distribute our application to app Store sir

Comment: You need create ADHOC distribution provisioning profile with your  user's device id (device id can be seen via iTunes once connected).

After that, you have to send this ADHOC distribution provisioning profile to the other user. We prepare the app with this profile, this app can run on those registered devices.

The Customer will download the app and drag it on iTunes and then sync his iPhone/iPod/iPad.

But, this application executable cannot be submitted to app-store and also won't run on any other devices other than those registered in the ADHOC distribution provisioning profile.

Comment: Ok.Thank U madam.But in the process of provisioning profile,device was not appear in itunes.How to identify device id.

Comment: When your device is connected to mac, it will sync with iTunes. There u will find the unique device id.

Comment: Instead of asking all this questions, it will really help you, if u read the getting started docs from apple.